# Validation for digit only in an EditText

Tags: java, android, validation

I am trying to make a simple functionality which the user inserts 2 numbers and a toast present the sum...
First, in order to do so, I would like to verify the user insert only digits. If not, I would like to set toast message (error) explains that only digits allow here. I use a boolean isdigit (EditText input) method.
However, I get an error -maybe because the for loop cannot accept null?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText firstIntCB, secundIntCB;
private Button getProductCB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addDataToDisplay();
}

public void addDataToDisplay() {
   if (isdigit(firstIntCB)==true && isdigit(secundIntCB)==true){
        firstIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
        secundIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secundNumber);
        getProductCB =(Button)findViewById(R.id.GetProduct);

        getProductCB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer intFirst = Integer.parseInt(firstIntCB.getText().toString());
                Integer intSec = Integer.parseInt(secundIntCB.getText().toString());
                String product = Integer.toString((int)Math.pow(intFirst,intSec));
                Toast.makeText
                        (getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(product), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

public boolean isdigit(EditText input) {
    String data=input.getText().toString().trim();
    for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)))
            return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this use **`android:inputType="number"`**
 property of `Editext` which allows only numbers to enter as input in `Editext`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"/>
```

for more information read **[android:inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType)**

and also bind your Controls in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firstIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    secundIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secundNumber);
    getProductCB =(Button)findViewById(R.id.GetProduct);

    addDataToDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `digits` and `inputType` properties in your `EditText`. `digits` property will allow user to enter specific character into your `EditText` so you don't need to add filter.

```
     <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="0123456789"/>
```

And you need to initialize your EditText before you use,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    secundIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secundNumber);
    getProductCB =(Button)findViewById(R.id.GetProduct);

    addDataToDisplay();
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this option but this is the easy way..
THX

Answer (score 0):

you are making a mistake..you should `findViewById` in your `onCreate` then do the other things.

the compiler try to resolve `if condition` but you not defined your edit text.

So:

```
`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    secundIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secundNumber);
    getProductCB =(Button)findViewById(R.id.GetProduct);


addDataToDisplay();
}
```

then put `android:inputType="number"` in your edit text xml

i hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

change your addDataToDisplay(); method like this

```
public void addDataToDisplay() {
    firstIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    secundIntCB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secundNumber);
    getProductCB =(Button)findViewById(R.id.GetProduct);

        getProductCB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isdigit(firstIntCB)==true && isdigit(secundIntCB)==true) {
                    Integer intFirst = Integer.parseInt(firstIntCB.getText().toString());
                    Integer intSec = Integer.parseInt(secundIntCB.getText().toString());
                    String product = Integer.toString((int) Math.pow(intFirst, intSec));
                    Toast.makeText
                            (getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(product), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Ok..  so i must use a setOnClickListener in order to check on real time if the input is valid ..

Comment: no @RonenRachmani that is a mistake. plz check the edited answer